# How to assign a public IP to container instance in azure using ARM template?

Tags: azure, dns, ip, azure-container-instances, azure-public-ip

I have created a container instance (the public one)... I am able to access the container using public IP(generated) and using FQDN. But I want to assign a static Public IP which I created using Public IP addresses in azure instead of auto-generated.

Could you help me,

1. how to assign the static IP to the container instance?
2. Can I use FQDN (Microsoft) to map to custom DNS record set (Azure)

Comment: Hello @sub , Can you please share the Arm Template that you are using ?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT Please find below link
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.containerinstance/aci-linuxcontainer-public-ip